# Is there a way to set a custom error page from cache for when the user has no internet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, error-handling, progressive-web-apps

I have searched the web far and wide and can't seem to find an answer.
I have a cshtml file in my cache that I want to display to users in case of their internet not working or the server being down. I have found a few articles about custom error handling in ASP.Net but they all require internet to be up.
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: If it's hosted in the intranet it's possible but if you're trying to access a website, without internet, but you still want to show an error, I don't think that's easy.

Comment: @JerdineSabio even if the page I want to display is already saved in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should search for java script code to check internet.
if a ajax call not work call checking internet function and then show a popup or message about internet.
I see something like this in google analytics.